# BigQuery loading incomplete dataset from Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to upload a dataset of Tweets from Cloud Storage. I have an schema based on https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-for-bigquery, but simpler, because I don't need all the fields.

I uploaded several files to Cloud Storage and then manually imported them from BigQuery. I have tried loading each file ignoring unknown fields, and not ignoring them. But I always end up with a table with lesser rows than the original dataset. Just in case, I took care of eliminating redundant rows from each dataset.

Example job-ids:

- cellular-dream-110102:job_ZqnMTr17Yx_KKGEuec3qfA0DWMo (loaded 1,457,794 rows, but the dataset contained 2,387,666)
- cellular-dream-110102:job_2xfbTFSvvs-unpP6xZXAfDeDjic (loaded 1,151,122 rows, but the dataset contained 3,265,405).

I don't know why this happens. I have tried to simplify the schema further, as well as ensuring that the dataset is clean (no repeated rows, no invalid data, and so on). The curious thing is that if I take a small sample of tweets (say, 10,000) and then upload the file manually, it works - it loads the 10,000 rows.

How can I find what is causing the problem?

Comment: From inspecting the load job's logs, it looks like some data failed to read. This should generate warnings in the error stream (assuming you are ignoring errors), but I don't see those in the job... There is something unexpected in the source .gz file you are loading. Can you share that source file with me (msheldon@google.com) so I can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Michael. I gave you permissions to read the files related to those jobs. The project is cellular-dream-110102. Thank you.